# Using Protocols in Objective C to Transfer Data Between Different Objects?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, protocols

Hey guys, I currently have a root table view which has a toolbar at the bottom and has labels and a refresh button within it, much like the Mail app's toolbar. This root table view controller obtains data from a server by allocating and initializing a DataUpdater class. Within this class are the NSURLConnection delegate methods that are called while communicating with the server.

As you can probably guess, I need to know when certain (delegate) functions are called within the DataUpdater class and the values of the parameters passed to these delegate functions so that I can update the labels on the toolbar accordingly (i.e. Connecting..., Updated, etc).

The problem I am having is determining how to notify the root table view controller of what is going on in these delegate methods. Would I use protocols, if so how? I have been skimming the documentation and don't quite see how I would get this effect. Or would you suggest I implement my program another way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A protocol is a kind of contract that says: *I promise to provide the non-optional methods defined in the protocol, and maybe even the optional ones.* It's purpose is like Java interfaces: to work around missing multiple-inheritence.

The delegate pattern in Objective-C normally works like this: you define a protocol, and then in your class, you define a variable like `id<MyProtocol> myDelegate;` and define a setter and maybe getter (either via normal methods, e.g. `- (void)setDelegate:(id<MyProtocol>)aDelegate;` or via properties.

Note that the delegate is *not* retained ! So if you work with a property, you need the `assign` option, not `retain`.

Now back in your class, you check whether `myDelegate` is nil and if not, you can directly call its non-optional methods. If you want to call an optional method, you first need to verify its presence via `respondsToSelector:`.

So if you decide to use the delegate pattern, you need to define a protocol, add that protocol to your root table view controller, implement the necessary methods there, and make sure to call `[foo setDelegate:self];` or something similar to inform your other class that the root table view controller is the delegate. And of course implement the delegate calls in your class.

**Edit:**

An alternative might be to use `NSNotification`s, BTW. The advantage of notifications is that you can have multiple objects listen and react to them. The disadvantage is that you cannot (directly) pass values back. For example, you can define a delegate method that asks the delegate whether to do something or not. That's not possible with notifications, it's more like shouting into a room instead of having a one-to-one conversation.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation, what I really needed to get me going, however, was a solid example which I found here: http://iphonedevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html Although that example retains the delegate rather than assigning it, I did the same and it doesn't seem to do anything detrimental at least initially. But I will take your and GorillaPatch's advice and use assign. ;) Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

DarkDust's answer about protocols is fine but I would like to add some things to it.

One underlying thing that is often forgotten when it comes to delegation is **object ownership**. When a program is running it creates a tree of objects. Its root object is the application delegate and for example it owns a navigation controller, which owns the individual view controllers, which own the view and the view owns its subviews and so on.

Often the question comes up: *"Why is the delegate not retained, just assigned?"* The problem is that if you send a message to a deallocated object the program crashes. So how do you make sure the delegate stays around? The answer is object ownership.

I give you an example: a UITableView and its data source which is the TableViewController which is nothing but a delegate. The TableViewController holds a reference with its view property to the UITableView, so it owns the TableView. That means when the tableView is alive there must also be its parent object present, which is the UITableView's delegate. So there is no danger that the delegate goes away somehow.

In the end it is again all about memory management.

**Take home message is: think upfront about object ownership will make your program mode modular, easier to maintain and will lead to a looser coupling between individual objects.**

Comment: You are welcome. I think it is sometimes hard to step back and have a look at the overall concepts, when one is digging deep in the frameworks.